# Merge devops automation release pipeline stage results

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-pipelines, test-reporting

I have a test automation devops release pipline with multiple stages with each stage running some specific testcategory test cases.
Each stage generates result.trx file. Is there any way to merge those test result files and get one report/result file.
Also each stage has been set for 2 attempts for failed test cases run.

[image]

Each stage has below tasks-

[image]